# Error in ASP MVC: an exception was thrown while trying to compile the transformation code

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2015

I am working on visual studio 2015, MVC, after creating my tables in data base and adding ADO.net entity data model, i got this error
[Error: an exception was thrown while trying to compile the transformation code. the following  exception was thrown...: Could not find part of the path:...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Cxb3.jpg)

Note: my system type = 64.

could you please help me

Comment: So? Do you have EF in your solution? Copy "EntityFramework.dll" into your project bin folder.

Comment: I found "EntitiyFramework.dll" when I open bin folder in my project, shall I copy and past it again?

Comment: Add reference to EntityFramework.dll again and then try

Comment: rebuild your whole solution after adding EF reference

Comment: I added " System.serviceModel.DomainServices.EntityFramework" reference again and rebuild the solution, I still show the error.

Comment: When I add new items in Model folder , there is a security warning : "running this text template can potentially harm your computer.